# Apache Camel transform JSON to POJO

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel

I'm trying to transform a simple JSON-file to a POJO in Apache Camel, but I cannot get it to work.

Routes.java

```
package org.acme.bindy.ftp;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.BindyType;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;


public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {        
        from("file:{{json.temp}}?delay=1000")   
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, WeatherForecast[].class)     
        .to("file:{{json.processed}}"); 
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

WeatherForecast.java

```
package org.acme.bindy.ftp;

import java.util.Objects;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


public class WeatherForecast {
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("temperatureC")
    private int temperatureC;
    @JsonProperty("temperatureF")
    private int temperatureF;
    @JsonProperty("summary")
    private String summary;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getTemperatureC() {
        return temperatureC;
    }

    public void setTemperatureC(int temperatureC) {
        this.temperatureC = temperatureC;
    }

    public int getTemperatureF() {
        return temperatureF;
    }

    public void setTemperatureF(int temperatureF) {
        this.temperatureF = temperatureF;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }
}
```

WeatherForecast-json

```
[{"date":"2022-05-07T13:49:22.0517663+02:00","temperatureC":36,"temperatureF":96,"summary":"Mild"},{"date":"2022-05-08T13:49:22.052558+02:00","temperatureC":21,"temperatureF":69,"summary":"Mild"},{"date":"2022-05-09T13:49:22.0525661+02:00","temperatureC":13,"temperatureF":55,"summary":"Hot"},{"date":"2022-05-10T13:49:22.0525665+02:00","temperatureC":-2,"temperatureF":29,"summary":"Warm"},{"date":"2022-05-11T13:49:22.0525668+02:00","temperatureC":49,"temperatureF":120,"summary":"Scorching"}]
```

**The error that I'm recieving is:**
No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has type: org.acme.bindy.ftp.WeatherForecast[] on: weather.json. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.acme.bindy.ftp.WeatherForecast[] to the required type: java.io.InputStream. Exchange[]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.acme.bindy.ftp.WeatherForecast[] to the required type: java.io.InputStream]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to occur **after** the (successful) unmarshalling to an array of `WeatherForecast` classes, when the obtained array of POJOs needs to be written to the filesystem:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, WeatherForecast[].class)     
.to("file:{{json.processed}}");
```

It's not surprising that Camel is expecting a converter to turn your body (an array of beans) into an inputstream in order to be able write it on disk

```
...to convert from type: org.acme.bindy.ftp.WeatherForecast[] to the required type: java.io.InputStream
```